# „Eine Datei hinlegen“ oder „eine Datei legen“

Tags: word-choice, idiomaticity

Wie sollte man richtig in informeller IT-Mail-Korrespondenz folgenden Satz schreiben, mit *hin-* oder ohne?

> Ich habe die Datei unter `C:\work` hingelegt.

vs

> Ich habe die Datei unter `C:\work` gelegt.

Der Sinn des Satzes ist <strike>„ich habe die Datei unter das Verzeichnis `C:\work` kopiert/hochgeladen.“</strike>
„Die Datei ist nun im Ordner `C:\work` zu finden und zu benutzen.“

Klingt die erste Version natürlich?

Comment: ich glaube du suchst nach dem wort **abgelegt**. "Ich habe die Date im Verzeichnis C:\work abgelegt"

Comment: @WayneEra es wird sich zeigen. Ich war mir sicher, ich habe dieses legen/hinlegen von einem deutschen Kollegen gehört. Vorerst werde ich die hier vorgeschlagenen Varianten nutzen.

Comment: wenn du dich auf "legen" fixieren willst, dann gäbe es auch die Möglichkeit zu sagen "ich habe etwas von x **nach** y **gelegt**", ist in der Umgangsprache zwar so möglich, aber klingt schon eher unprofessionell

Comment: @WayneEra danke, das habe ich gebraucht! Das würde dann eigentlich dem englischen "put a file" oder dem russischen "положить файл" entsprechen, was in den Sprachen für ITler ganz ok klingt. Aus meiner Erfahrung klingt die ITler-Sprache halt so locker und unprofessionell.

Comment: Das kann ich aus meiner Erfahrung als Informatiker bestätigen ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass

"Ich habe die Datei unter ... abgelegt" bedeutet, dass es eine Regel gibt, dass die Datei da hingehört.

"Ich habe die Datei in ... hingelegt" würde ich verwenden, wenn es keine klare Regel gab, wo sie denn nun hingehört, und ich die selbst Entscheidung getroffen habe, sie eben dort abzulegen.

Der Unterschied ist allerdings wirklich minimal, aber ich würde beide Formen verwenden. Die Form mit "ich habe die Datei .... gelegt" ist mir aber wirklich nicht geläufig.

Answer (score 21):

in der Regel werden Dateien "abgelegt".

Siehe hierzu auch [Wikipedia: Dateisystem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dateisystem).

Das Beispiel ist demnach

> Ich habe die Datei unter C:\work abgelegt.

Answer (score 5):

Informell würde ich zu *kopiert* tendieren – dies ist meiner Einschätzung nach der allgemeine Term, insbesondere im IT-Zusammenhang.

> Ich habe die Datei nach `C:\work` kopiert.

Unter Umständen würde ich *verschoben* benutzen, wenn ich betonen wollte, dass die Datei nicht mehr an ihrem ursprünglichen Ort ist – aber das ist dann schon wieder ein wenig technisch.

> Ich habe die Datei nach `C:\work` verschoben.

Das von PhilippD vorgeschlagene *abgelegt* klingt für meine Begriffe eher formell, und ich würde erwarten, dass es in erster Linie in Verwaltungen benutzt wird.

Also Antwort auf deinen Kommentar: Wenn du die Tatsache betonen willst, dass die Datei ab jetzt in dem Ordner verfügbar ist (aber das ergibt sich natürlich aus der Tatsache, dass du sie kopiert hast):

> Die Datei ist ab jetzt in `C:\work` verfügbar. (ziemlich formell)
>
> Die Datei befindet sich in `C:\work`.  (immer noch formell)
>
> Die Datei ist in `C:\work`. (informell)
>
> Die Datei liegt in `C:\work`.

Letzteres kommt deinem Vorschlag wohl am nächsten – eine Datei *legen* klingt für mich irgendwie komisch, aber eine Datei kann durchaus in einem Ordner *liegen*.

Wenn du eine neue Datei in `C:\work` erstellt hast:

> Ich habe die Datei unter `C:\work\abc.doc` gespeichert. (halbwegs informell, normalerweise würde ich noch den Dateinamen hinzufügen)
>
> Ich habe die Datei in `C:\work` erstellt. (relativ formell)

Comment: sorry, ich habe wohl falsch den Sinn erklärt. Ich will eigentlich betonen, das die Datei ab jetzt in dem Ordner zu finden und zu benutzen ist. Ich wollte ich nicht betonen, dass ich eine Kopie erstellt habe oder sonst etwas mit dem Kopieren verbundenes.

Comment: "kopiert" would still be the word of choice for me. While it technically means that you "copied it" (instead of "moving", "deleting"), it is generally used for "the file is in the new location now". The only case where this does not work, is when you created a new file (e.g. a document) from scratch in a certain location.

Comment: bist ITler? Du würdest wohl auch nicht sagen: "Die Datei wiegt 4MB", wah :) ?

Comment: If you just want to say that the file is in C:\work, I would use "ist", just as in English.

Comment: nah genug dran :) Und ich hab gerade festgestellt, dass ich unabsichtlich in englisch geantwortet habe - sorry.

Comment: "Abgelegt" wird durchaus in der Praxis verwendet. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Dateien werden nicht *gelegt* (Hühner legen etwas, nämlich Eier) und auch nicht hingelegt. Man legt z.B. ein Buch irgendwo hin, oder man legt sich selbst hin um ein Nickerchen zu machen.

Dateien werden normalerweise gespeichert oder abgespeichert:

> Ich habe die Datei unter C:\work *gespeichert*.
>   Ich habe die Datei unter C:\work *abgespeichert*.

<sub>*Das erste Wort eines Satzes (hier »ich«) schreibt man übrigens immer mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben.*</sub>

Wenn man tatsächlich eine Kopie einer Datei speichert, also nicht, wie meist üblich, eine neue oder eine veränderte Datei speichert, kann man das auch so sagen:

> Ich habe die Datei *nach* C:\work kopiert.

Beachte hier auch die andere Präposition:

- Das Speichern oder Abspeichern ist eine Aktion, die man an einem bestimmten Ort vornimmt. Es handelt sich - zumindest grammatisch - nicht um eine Bewegung. Daher speichert man etwas *an* einem Ort, oder auch *unter* einem Verzeichnis.
- Das Kopieren ist grammatisch eine Bewegung zu einem bestimmten Ziel hin. Daher kopiert man etwas *nach* XY.

Vergleichbar mit dem Kopieren ist auch das Verschieben:

> Ich habe die Datei nach C:\work verschoben.

Comment: Dateien werden zwar nicht gelegt, überlicherweise sehr wohl aber abgelegt.

Comment: @Jan: Stimmt, stand aber nicht zur Auswahl. Der OP sprach nicht von *ablegen*, sondern nur von *legen* und *hinlegen*. Da aber das Verb *ablegen* im Zusammenhang mit Dateien meiner Beobachtung nach selten verwendet wird, habe ich es nicht erwähnt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast was steht für OP, denn :) ?

Comment: @RomanT: OP = Original Poster, hier also der Fragensteller. Und dieser hat in seiner Frage nach *hinlegen* und *legen*, nicht aber nach *ablegen* gefragt.